# Is there a validated questionnaire on consumer well-being?

Tags: perception, reference-request, methodology, test, well-being

I am conducting a study comparing different cigarettes in terms of their relative toxicity. As a side analysis, I wish to see if a novel cigarette, purportedly less toxic, is similarly pleasurable.

Participants will only smoke one cigarette, so I would like to use a validated questionnaire of instantaneous well-being and satisfaction. Are there any?

Comment: I don't know why you think you need that instead of a product satisfaction questionnaire, the questions of which depend on the type of product being evaluated. So look for such a product questionnaire for your specific industry.

Comment: @Fizz My goal is not simply to appraise satisfaction, but also trying to understand whether these new tobacco products can similarly gratify and assuade craving as combustion cigarettes do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many consumer satisfaction tests available, see for a somewhat dated but informative review [Westbrook & Oliver (1981)](http://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/9791/volumes/v08/NA-08). Most often, simple, single-item rating scales are employed. Reportedly, there is little uniformity in the number of scale steps used and in the anchoring. They often range from 3-point labeled rating scales (*e.g.*., good - neutral - bad) to 10- and 11-point variants labeled only at the extremes and midpoint (*e.g.*, 0= bad; 5 = neutral; 10= excellent).

An interesting consumer questionnaire I found was devised by [Lou *et al*. (2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479706000211). It was devised for assessing people's satisfaction with drinking water and consisted of a general part I with personal information (Fig. 1), and a part II specifically testing consumer satisfaction (Fig. 2). Because the authors targeted specifically the defining characteristics of drinking water based on the [Water Taste and Odor Wheel](http://www.connecticutradon.com/blog-1/topic/foul-odor-in-water) you might want to adapt certain questions in part II to match your specific needs.

[image: part I]
<sup>Fig. 1. Part I. General information. source: [Lou *et al*. (2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479706000211)</sup>

[image: part II]
<sup>Fig. 2. Part II. Consumer satisfaction. source: [Lou *et al*. (2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479706000211)</sup>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Lou *et al*. *J Environmental Management* (2007); **82**(1): 1-12](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479706000211)

**-** [Westbrook & Oliver, *Advances Consumer Res* (1981); **8**: 94-99](http://www.acrwebsite.org/volumes/9791/volumes/v08/NA-08)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was also looking at something with some more in depth psychological details (eg pleasure vs satisfaction).